# how to disable the button color in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a set of 5 buttons which I created in winforms using c#,if i click the button1 it should change to green color.,then if button2 is clicked then it should change to green.,but button1 should change to its original color.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            {
                button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                button2.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
                button3.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
                button4.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
                button5.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
            button2.BackColor = Color.Green;
            button3.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
            button4.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
            button5.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
            button2.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
            button3.BackColor = Color.Green;
            button4.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
            button5.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
        }
    }
}
```

but this code will be hectic if i have many buttons.,please help me out of this.

Comment: Loop through the control control collection for the buttons involved (put them in a panel to ensure that you don't mess with any other buttons that you don't want to affect) and set all but the sender to lavender while setting the sender to green.

Comment: Loop the container of the buttons, check if sender if that control and set the backcolor.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a single event handler and assign it to `Click` event of all your buttons:

```
private void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // iterate over all buttons on form
    foreach (var button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        button.BackColor = button == sender ? Color.Green : Color.Lavender;
}
```

As @CharlesMay stated in comment, be aware, that this code will find each and any `Button` that is direct child of your form. There is some ways to avoid it:

**1. Hold you buttons in a container.** For example create a `Panel` (say `myPanel`) and place all of this buttons on that panel, then iterate over that panel's controls:

```
foreach (var button in myPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>())
```

**2. Store you active button in a private field.** This way you don't need to iterate over controls at all:

```
private Button _activeButton = null;

private void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // disable previosly active button
    if (_activeButton != null) _activeButton.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
    // set new button
    _activeButton = sender as Button;
    // enable currently active button
    if (_activeButton != null) _activeButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SetActive(Button active)
        {
            foreach(var btn in new[] {button1, button2, button3, button4, button5})
            {
               btn.BackColor = btn == active ? Color.Green : Color.Lavender;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetActive(button1);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetActive(button2);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetActive(button3);
        }
    }
}
```